# SQL select between dates, but show all when start and end date are empty

Tags: sql-server, date, select, null, between

In SQL, I can use wildcard '%' on string and Select statement will show all the records like

```
select * from tablea where title like '%'
```

My question is what if both the start and end date are empty in the BETWEEN & AND function in Select statement.

Example

```
`select * from table where inputdate between '2014-01-01'` and '2014-01-31'
```

It works fine in this statement because there are start and end date.

What if there isn't any start and end date, and I want to show all the records?

`select * from table where inputdate between '%' and '%'`   <--- not working.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your query in a way that `inputdate` column is evaluated against the value passed or if the no value is passed to @StartDate variable just pick earliest possible date,

I have select 1900-01-01 as the earliest date but depending on your column type you can pick a more appropriate substitute start and end dates.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate   DATE = '2014-01-31'

select * from table 
where inputdate >=  COALESCE(@StartDate, '19000101') 
  and inputdate <=  COALESCE(@EndDate  , '99991231')
```

### Dynamic SQL

Another better way of handling this kind of query with optional parameters will be using dynamic sql something like this...

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate   DATE = '2014-01-31'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM Table 1 = 1 '
          + CASE WHEN @StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 
           N' AND inputdate >= @StartDate ' ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN @EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 
           N' AND inputdate <= @EndDate '   ELSE N' ' END

Execute sp_executesql @Sql 
                     ,N'@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE'
                     ,@StartDate
                     ,@EndDate
```

Comment: what if both StartDate and EndDate are both empty, and then I want to show all the records from the table when they are empty.Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yep this query will show all records if both were null. Or will put a cap on upper or lower range depending what variable was provided a value.

Comment: by the way what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I just tried, and it works, if the start and end date are null, it will use '19000101' and '99991231' instead. Thanks alot.

Comment: I am using SQL2008 r2.

Comment: Another more sleek solution would be to use dynamic sql with this kind of optional parameters in your query see my update.

Answer (score 0):

wildcard can only be used on string, But since you mentioned the column is Date, you can do something better. Date min/max has been defined in almost all DBMS, IDK about the max but the min is usually  January 1, 1753. so you can try between ' January 1, 1753' and 'date max'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.Date >= IIF(@FromDate IS NULL, t.Date, @FromDate) 
AND t.Date <= IIF(@ToDate IS NULL, t.Date, @ToDate)
```

works fine.